# How to make custom library container for Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries, eclipse-jdt

So, I need to use lots of libraries.

Usually I just added the libraries through Java build path, but when I added lots of libraries, it is complicated and it is not manageable.

So I have searched some ways to resolve this problem.

So I found that I can use `org.eclipse.jdt`.

I want to input three jar files to my custom container which name is `sqldriver`.

- mariadb-java-client.jar
- mysql-connector-java.jar
- ojdbc6.jar

and I will use the libraries programmatically like this

- `new sqldriver.oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()`
- `new sqldriver.com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver()`

Is this possible?

or I just want to manage three jars in one container.

Can you help me?

I need some examples to make my own custom container.

Let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a tiny Eclipse plug-in providing two things:

- An [IClasspathContainer](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IClasspathContainer.html)
- A [ClasspathContainerInitializer](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ClasspathContainerInitializer.html)

The initializer will have to be registered at the [classpathContainerInitializer extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_core_classpathContainerInitializer.html?cp=3_1_1_2).

As an example I suggest you have a look at JDT's [JUnitContainerInitializer](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/buildpath/JUnitContainerInitializer.java).